# Exception while printing an exception trough logging.exception()

Tags: python, docker, logging, character-encoding, traceback

I have a **try** block which raises an exception every time, in **except** block I  used `logging.exception('some message')` to log error. But while handling the above exception another exception occurred.

```
    try:
        raise Exception('')
        #some key error exception raised.
    except Exception as e:
        abortMsg = "some error"
        logging.exception(abortMsg)
        return
```

I'am pretty sure that the error is caused by the stack trace of the exception,Any operation related to it like printing it , or using `traceback.print_exc()` raises exceptions recursively

The error log when i used `traceback.print_exc()`

Error log:

```
--- Logging error ---
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Thread._bootstrap of <Thread(Thread-5, 
started 139762597885696)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "somefile.py", line 570, in postProcess
reporter.write_report()
File "someotherfile.py", line 115, in write_report
File "someotherfile.py", line 295, in _addSectionResult
File "someotherfile.py", line 315, in _addCheckSummary
KeyError: 'message_zero'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/somefile.py", line 310, in execute
  self.postProcess()
  File "/somefile.py", line 580, in postProcess
  s = str(traceback.print_exc())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 159, in print_exc
  print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), limit=limit, file=file, chain=chain)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 100, in print_exception
  type(value), value, tb, limit=limit).format(chain=chain):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 474, in __init__
  capture_locals=capture_locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 358, in extract
  f.line
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 282, in line
  self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 16, in getline
lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
lines = fp.readlines()
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 4: invalid start byte'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 980, in emit
msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 830, in format
return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 575, in format
record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 525, in formatException
traceback.print_exception(ei[0], ei[1], tb, None, sio)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 100, in print_exception
type(value), value, tb, limit=limit).format(chain=chain):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 487, in __init__
self._load_lines()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 500, in _load_lines
self.__context__._load_lines()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 498, in _load_lines
frame.line
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 282, in line
self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 16, in getline
lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
lines = fp.readlines()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 4: invalid start byte
```

Is there any way to see and analyse stack trace which is causing error?

PS : I'm using this inside a docker. While i run this file locally no recursive exception is raised.

EDIT : Any exception raised from anywhere from the code is causing recursive exception(unicode decode error)

Comment: What are the `locale` settings on your machine and in docker?

Comment: using python 3.5.2 on both my machine and docker, using ubuntu 16.04 on both

Comment: I meant, what's the output of running `locale` in the terminal?

Comment: my docker locale 'LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL='

Comment: my machine locale 'LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL='

Comment: And the output of `locale charmap` in each of them?

Comment: UTF-8 in both of them